# junit4: How to call the other class static method in junit4 @before or @Test?

Tags: java, junit4

How to call the other class static method in junit4 `@Before` or `@Test`?

I have an question about how to call the other class method in junit4 `@Test` or `@Before`?

For example, I wrote a `static` method in `UtilTool`

```
public static String readAllBytes(String filePath) {
    String content = "";

    try {
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;
}
```

Use the define method in junit4 `@Before`:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("setUp......");
    UtilTool.readAllBytes("/tmp/test.txt")
```

But I will get the following error messages when I call the `readAllBytes` method from `UtilTool` in Junit4 `@Before` or `@Test`

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: .....
```

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like a compile problem to me. How are you building/running your tests? Maven?

Comment: I just compile my project by idea, I am not using maven.

Comment: If I declare readAllBytes method in Junit Test class, it will work well.

Comment: To expand on what @BoristheSpider said, it sounds like when you run the test, it accesses a compilation of `UtilTool` that is not up to date. Check the classpath when running the test and figure out where it gets its classes.

Comment: Can you post the import statements in your Test class and the package name where your UtilTool class is stored?

Comment: Try rebuild project in your ide. Looks like old version of `UtilTool` is used.

Comment: java -Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/teset/qa_test -cp /opt/test/qa_test/sentry-test/target/classes:/opt/test/qa_test/sentry-test/target/test-classes/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestServerAll --> TestServerAll is Junit Test class, UtilTool class is in /target/classes and TestServerAll class is in target/test-classes/

Comment: I have re-builded the project, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this issue, I made a stupid mistake. I forgot replace the older jar in classpath. thanks!

Comment: Ideally, a question that might not be reproducible should be closed than answered. This doesn't qualify being an answer.